# How to change date format in laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, date-format

I got a problem

```
Call to a member function dateFormat() on string
```

This is my CollectionController.php

```
public function create(Request $req)
    {
        try {
            $collection = new Collection();
            $collection->NameCollection = $req->input('NameCollection');
            $collection->Description = $req->input('Description');
            $collection->LogoImagePath = $req->input('LogoImagePath');
            $collection->WallPaperPath = $req->input('WallPaperPath');
            $collection->StartOn = $req->input('StartOn')->dateFormat();
            $collection->EndOn = $req->input('EndOn');
            $collection->CoverImagePath = $req->input('CoverImagePath');
            $collection->save();
            return $collection;
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

This is my Collection.php in View

```
class Collection extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'Collection';
    protected $primaryKey = 'IDCollection';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I want StartOn is "2022-12-06" but my function is not correct. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Carbon`:

```
$collection->StartOn = Carbon::parse($req->input('StartOn'))->format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But are you checking the format of request data ? maybe it has the right format and you don't need to format it

Comment: Yea. I got it. Tks u so much for your support